# kafka to spark streaming java api issues

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am a beginner with Kafka and spark. I want to do real-time processing on data I am receiving from kafka on a specific topic through spark streaming. I am not able to use JavaPairReceiverInputDStream as returned by the createStream function .

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName(
                "testwordCount");
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf,
                Durations.seconds(1));

        Map<String, Integer> topics_map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        topics_map.put("Customtopic", 10);

JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> kafkaStream = KafkaUtils
                .createStream(jssc, "localhost:2181", "kafkasparkconsumer",
                        topics_map);
```

The code below gives an error :

```
 JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = kafkaStream.map(
                 new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
                 @Override public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) {
                 return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1);
                 }
                 }).reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
                 @Override
                 public Integer call(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
                 return i1 + i2;
                 }
                 });
                 wordCounts.print();
```

The method map(Function,R>) in the type JavaPairDStream is not applicable for the arguments (new PairFunction(){})  SparkStreamingKafka.java    /Kafka-Spark/src/com/sd/kafka   line 43 Java Problem

The spark version I am using is 1.2.0. I couldn't find examples for java api for dealing with kafka messages. Can anyone tell me what do I need to change?

Answer (score 7):

You call the wrong method.  In java if you want to get a Pair, you should call [MapToPair](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/api/java/JavaDStreamLike.html#mapToPair(org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction)).  Try this code:

```
JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> pairs = kafkaStream
            .mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<String, String>, String, Integer>() {
                @Override public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(Tuple2<String, String> word) throws Exception {
                    return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(word._2(), 1);
                }
            }).reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
                @Override public Integer call(Integer integer, Integer integer2) throws Exception {
                    return integer + integer2;
                }
            });

    pairs.print();

    jssc.start();
    jssc.awaitTermination();
```

Answer (score 0):

kafkaStream return a tuple. Check this

```
JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> kafkaStream = KafkaUtils
                .createStream(jssc, "localhost:2181", "kafkasparkconsumer",
                        topics_map);
JavaDStream<String> lines = kafkaStream
                .map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
                    /**
                     * 
                     */
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
                        return tuple2._2();
                    }
                });
```